# How to drop or skip data type mismatch while reading from Mongo using Spark Mongo Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I am trying to read from Mongo using spark Mongo connector trying to load 100M+ rows.

Does anyone know how I can ignore rows if there is a datatype mismatch using my predefined schema? There are some date fields that are timestamps but someone inserted String type. There are similar issues with other fields.

I want to know how we can handle datatype mismatch, The `DROPMALFORMED` functionality is not available in Spark Mongo Connector.

Any advice or pointers will be helpful.

`spark-mongo-connector 10.1.1, delta 2.3, Spark EMR 3.3`

For example, there is a `field1` which is the Date type in Mongo and one of the records is inserted as a String type of date or wrong value, and `field2` is in Integer type but again one or more records are inserted as String and so on.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can be better able to provide help.

Comment: You can read all columns as string using `primitivesAsString` option & then cast it to specific data type.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

````
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.read.format("mongo").load()

val correctedDf = df
  .withColumn("field1", when($"field1".cast("date").isNotNull, $"field1".cast("date"))
                           .otherwise(lit(null))) // Replace with appropriate default for your use-cas
    ```
````

Comment: I will try this, but not sure how this will scale as I have multiple nested structure with 100+fields. Do you know anything that helps to skip records when spark encounters such issue or just print which records is having the this data and continue processing without failing. Write now spark just fails when it trys to write in delta